# Access a static global WinForm UI object from multiple files

Tags: c++, winforms

I'm trying to change the `TextBox->Text` on my main UI from multiple places.

I've got a `GUI.h` which includes the VS2013 default WinForm construction code as well as some methods and variables.

I've commented out some things I've tried, but the basic idea can be seen in many forms:

**I'm trying to get a handle or reference to the *one* UI for the whole program.**

The current solution I'm trying to work with includes a `ref struct Globals{}` from which I can access the `GUI gui`.

```
//GUI.h

namespace GUI_Example_Receive {

    public ref class GUI : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
        public:
            GUI(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //
                //TODO: Add the constructor code here
                //
            }
            //static GUI ^gui = nullptr;
            /*
            static GUI^ GetGUI(){
                static GUI gui = gcnew GUI;
            }
            */

       //UI Construction code

      void SetConsoleTextBoxText(System::String^ input)
      {
        this->consoleTextBox->Text = input;
      }

      System::Void startButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
      {
        Thread^ t1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &GUI::ContinueNormally));
        t1->Start();
        //t1->Join();
      }
    };

    ref struct Globals {
        static GUI ^gui;
    };


    //static gcroot<GUI ^> gui = gcnew GUI;
}
```

I implement these in `GUI.cpp`. The important bits to note are that `ContinueNormally()` calls a `while(true)` loop, constantly reading from a broadcast. Thus, in order to maintain control of the UI, that loop must be called on a separate thread. I'm currently using `Invoke()` to do so, though I was using a different solution earlier.

In `Start()`, you can see where I define `Globals::gui` and run the UI.

```
//GUI.cpp

void GUI::ContinueNormally() //Object^ data for threading purposes?
{
    //Setup

    Example::EntityStatePduProcessor processor; //defined here and used during the while loop

    //BufferRecieveLoop();
    this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(&BufferRecieveLoop));
    /*System::Threading::Thread^ t1 = 
        gcnew System::Threading::Thread(
        gcnew System::Threading::ParameterizedThreadStart(BufferRecieveLoop));
    t1->Start();
    t1->Join();*/

    //Cleanup
}

static void Start()
{
    Globals::gui = gcnew GUI;
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(Globals::gui);

    //gui = gcnew GUI;
    //System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(gui);
}

int __cdecl main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    System::Windows::Forms::Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Start();

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I have a file with one large method which is called continuously from my `while(true)` loop and attempts to access my `Globals::gui` object, but **seems to change a non-visible `GUI` object's `TextBox->Text` instead of the one I want to act as the `static global GUI`**

```
//EntityStatePduProcessor.cpp

void EntityStatePduProcessor::Process(const DIS::Pdu& packet)
{
    GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->SetConsoleTextBoxText("eventually a std::ostringstream");
}
```

---

It is quite possible that I am having issues because I'm on a different thread trying to access the `GUI`'s method. I'm not sure how to correctly `Invoke()` a method in this example.

Comment: Make a public property to get/set text of `TextBox`. Keep reference to the main form in a public static field/property of a class like `Program`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've got a public set method for the textbox. Keeping reference is what I'm struggling with and it's a bit tricky because `GUI` is a `ref class`. Could you further explain what you mean by "public static field/property of a class"?

Comment: The thread does not do anything useful, it invokes right back to the UI thread.  It is not clear to me what BufferRecieveLoop() does, but if it "loops" then your UI stops working.  You'd actually update the Text property but you just can't see it because the controls can no longer paint themselves.  The looping must be done on the worker thread, only use BeginInvoke() where necessary to update the UI.  BackgroundWorker is a class that helps you get this right.

Comment: @HansPassant  this would be more appropriate in another question, but I don't want to split things.

I changed things to get rid of threads to test your theory:

`GUI.h` now does not start a thread for `ContinueNormally()` and instead just calls the method.

`GUI.cpp` also normally calls `BufferRecieveLoop()` instead of Invoking it.

Now when `EntityStatePduProcessor.cpp` calls `SetConsoleTextBoxText()`, it still changes a different Form than the one visible. I know this because I check what the textbox contains with `auto temp = this->consoleTextBox->Text;` and it is what I set it to.

Comment: The above comment got too long. I've tried to call `this->consoleTextBox->Invalidate();` and `this->Invalidate();` within my `SetConsoleTextBoxText()` method to force a visual update/repaint. Me not seeing any changes tells me it's a different Form that's being changed. Though I could just be doing that incorrectly.  Furthermore, it could actually not update because it's stuck within that `while(true)` loop and won't display a redraw/repaint/Invalidate, but that doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Refresh()` instead of `Invalidate()`

In C# form projects I've made, `Invalidate()` was used to repaint controls. For some reason, that isn't working in this project, but `this->consoleTextBox->Refresh()` repaints my textbox.

I am now dealing with an unresponsive form due to a constantly looping `while(true)` on the main thread, but that's for a different question.